# Lookup table vs. multiple choice questions

Tags: commcare

I want to add municipality and town to my form exports to be able to use them as data disaggregates in my analysis. I don't have a large number of options (four municipalities and ten towns). I would like to have the function of sorting the towns based on the municipality, and my question is:

Is it better to use a lookup table, or to create a series of multiple choice questions with display conditions based on the municipality selection? Is there an advantage to one approach over the other? (Assume the subscription will not limit my access to lookup tables)

Answer (score 1):

I'd almost always use a lookup table in this scenario because:

1. If the list does change you can update it with "Sync with Server" instead of having to make a new build and have everyone Update App
2. You can reuse that list of locations in other forms in your app and still maintain the list in just one place (rather than having to edit multiple forms each time the locations change.
3. That approach will scale better if your list ever grows larger. Otherwise, you'd have to make a new multiple choice questions for each new municipality. So if that list grows to 10 municipalities you have 10 mutiple choice questions.
4. It's about the same complexity as a series of multiple choice questions since you'd have to make a hidden value that coalesces all the town questions into one "town" hidden value to save to the case.

The only exception I would say are if the person that will maintain the form is a very basic user and would have trouble updating lookup tables with the Excel import. It's a little more transparent what is happening if you put it all in the form, but it creates more overhead that's probably not worth it.